# Alias for input parameters in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we have aliases(some form of metadata) for input parameters in a stored procedure? 
EX:

@busDate to be called as 'Business Date'

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. The parameter must start with the @ sign and follow the rules for [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) (no special characters, no spaces, etc). The best you could do would be something like `@Business_Date`.

Comment: I agree that as per rules we cannot have special characters as parameter names. My ideas wasnt to name the variable as 'Business Date'. I have a scenario where stored procs are called from gui at runtime and gui should be able to understand what each param is business terms. Ofcourse I can always have a table with metadata but wanted to know if there was an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add comments in the code, but there is no mechanism to supply a description that is visible elsewhere.

One thing that you can to is to use descriptive names, e.g. `@BusinessProposalDraftText` rather than `@busPrpDftTx`. Even if it is more to type, it's still easier to spell regular words than to get abbreviations exactly the same.